# FBAsyncInit auto script loading

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

In some of the docs, the FbAsyncInit ends with:

```
(function() { 
    var e = document.createElement('script'); 
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'; 
    e.async = true; 
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e); 
 }());
```

while in some other docs it ends like this:

```
  (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  } (document));
```

Which one of these is the correct one to use?  or are they interchangeable?

also,

i noticed that sometimes the docs want you to add the html header:

```
xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
```

and somewhere else they refer to it as:

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

which one of these is correct?
which one is faster?

It seems that different pages of the documentation are written by different teams...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one of these is the correct one to use? or are they interchangeable?

They are interchangeable; just two slightly different methods of doing basically the same thing. I’d prefer the second version – it’s main advantage being that it sets an id on the script element, and thereby would not load it twice if the function would happen to be placed twice in the same page.

> which one of these is correct?

Both are. A namespace on the HTML element it necessary for XFBML to work in older IE – where it actually „points” to doesn’t matter.

> which one is faster?

They have no impact on „speed” whatsoever, since the URL given is only an identifier for the namespace, it’s not actually fetched by the browser. You can also put http;//example.com/my-own-fancy-namespace in there if you like …